# Whats wrong with my jquery here? - I am trying to submit this without having a refresh effect on the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

The button seems to trigger the JQuery, but the ajax isn't POSTing the data to the php file. If I place alert("working"); in the success, it won't alert.

```
echo "
     <input type='submit' class='primaryButton' value='Cancel' id='cancel-button' style='display: float; float: left; margin-right: 1.5%;' onclick='return confirm(&quot;Cancel Ticket?&quot;)'>
     ";



$( "#cancel-button" ).click(function() {
    var ticketID = "<?php echo($_GET['id']); ?>";
    var ticketPosition = "ticket";
    var cancelTicketAuth = "G7D9-F9D8-S0BD-C8F9-D03F-G8V9";
    var dataStringCancel = "ticketID=" + ticketID + "&ticket-position=" + ticketPosition + "&cancelTicketAuth=" + cancelTicketAuth;
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '../../php/ticket/cancelTicket.php',
        data: dataStringCancel,
        success: function (CancelTicketReturn) {

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please show the errors from your browser console

Comment: I see the issue, its ReferenceError: e is not defined, but what do I set the 'e' to on the preventDefault?

Comment: function(e) Please add e in your function parameters

Comment: Just change your button to `<input type='button'` then you don't need preventdefault.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the parameter event (`e`) to the click function: `function(e) {`

```
$( "#cancel-button" ).click(function(e) {
    // Dont use the onclick on your submit button.  
    // Let jQuery handle it. 
    if(confirm("Cancel Ticket?") == false) return;

    var ticketID = "<?php echo($_GET['id']); ?>";
    var ticketPosition = "ticket";
    var cancelTicketAuth = "G7D9-F9D8-S0BD-C8F9-D03F-G8V9";
    var dataStringCancel = "ticketID=" + ticketID + "&ticket-position=" + ticketPosition + "&cancelTicketAuth=" + cancelTicketAuth;
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '../../php/ticket/cancelTicket.php',
        data: dataStringCancel,
        success: function (CancelTicketReturn) {

        }
    });
});
```

> EventData
>
> Type: Anything
>   An object containing data that will be passed to the event handler.
>   https://api.jquery.com/click/